# Why numeric up/down control coming when one of my model property is integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to show textbox when my model property has integer type.

this is how my controller and view code looks

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.Employee
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.Id = 101;
    return View(emp);
}
```

Model

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

where i made the mistake for which numeric up/down is getting render for my id property. what to change in code so textbox should appear for id property. i do not want to change id property's data type. thanks

Comment: Use `TextBoxFor()` not `EditorFor()` (which will display the browsers HTML5 implementation of a numeric input if one exists)

Comment: anyone can tell me why EditorFor() render numeric up/down for integer type model field. what is the reason. please explain. thanks

Comment: Because that's what `EditorFor()` does. Your type is `int` so the `EditorFor()` method adds `type="number"` to the `<input>` tag (`TextBoxFor()` will add `type="text"`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EditorFor()` method uses the [TemplatesHelpers](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs) class to determine which `EditorTemplate` to use for rendering the html (for example, taking into account any custom `EditorTemplates` for the type, a `[UiHint]` or `[DataType]` attribute if one exists and the type itself. In the case of `int`, the inbuilt default template generates

```
<input type="number" name="Id" .... />
```

which will render the browsers HTML5 implementation of a number up-down input if supported.

If you do not want this, then use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
```

which will render `type="text"`

Answer (score 3):

You can continue using EditorFor, just change `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)` to `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, "Text")`.

The `"Text"` means you want to use the text template instead of the default template for that type.